# Android WebView doesn't load HTML

Tags: android, webview, chromium

since the release of new version of WebView in Android (I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 55.0.2883.91 (code 288309110)) my app cannot load HTML I have used previously without problems.

The error is this:
W/chromium: [WARNING:navigator_impl.cc(299)] Refusing to load for invalid virtual URL:
And following the HTML I intend to display.

HTML is normal page (I use the tags  etc. and some texts).

For HTML loading, I use:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "utf-8", html);
```

HTML is stored in html String variable.

Do you have any suggestions what can I do? HTML I want to display contains javascript. The String variable also contains some parts with escaped characters like this:

> %3Chtml%3E%3Chead%3E%3Cscript%20type%3D%22text%2Fjavascript%22%3E%20

Comment: I guess it can be something with the last parameter - I have no idea why I set it to the same as content...

Answer (score 0):

For Enabling Javascript:-

```
   //Enable Javascript
    WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```